# Should we allow answers that contain hard-coded values?

Tags: discussion, answers, code

I've seen answers where values in the example code are hard-coded.  An example might be

```
if (name === "Robert") {
} else if (name === "John") {
}
```

It isn't considered best practice to hard-code values like this in an application; depending on the purpose there are different alternative solutions that are preferable.

Should answers with hard-coded values like this be acceptable?  Or should they be downvoted?

Comment: I don't see why explicitly setting a text property to a literal string should be some overwhelming problem, especially for MCVE.

Comment: Your current example, as far as I'm aware, isn't something that's considered "bad practice" and does in fact have various usages. The example Will had initially put in is something that could be considered not best practice. _At the same time,_ hard coding a string _for an example block of code_ is not necessarily a bad thing. If you want to show how something would work to help someone, for instance, figure out how to sanitize a string, a hard-coded test value until you've got the code working isn't a terrible thing. It just should be replace after the code is working.

Comment: @Kendra, No solution is bad. But what if I have another 20 more names to be validated before executing some actions? So, Should I write rule engine or have the conditions some place, where this can be configurable.

Comment: Your comment is a bit unclear- Are you meaning what if you have another 20 names to validate in that `if else` statement? In that case, an `if else` is highly unlikely to be the thing you'd want to use. I'm not saying _that example_ is always a good idea, I'm just saying that it has its place. For instance, if the name is "John" I want to give them five dollars. Otherwise, if the name is "Steve" I want to collect the twenty bucks I've given them before. For all other names, I want to greet them politely. That would be an `if else` use case. If I need to do something unique for each name (cont)

Comment: (cont) I would _not_ be using an `if else` to do it, I'd fine some other way to handle it, depending on if the number of names is finite and various other factors. The example Will gave is something you'd very rarely want to find in production code. Like Ed said below, there _are_ cases where you basically need to have hard-coded values, but most of the time you won't want a hard-coded string in production code.

Comment: @Kendra, no excuses in hardcording your applications. No standard and best practices allow them. Quote me an example, where hardcoding is unavoidable? THanks.

Comment: Ed gave you an example below. Learn to be a bit flexible and realize that not everything is going to fit exactly how you want it to. I've seen a good programmer go into a fit of rage over something that "was not best practice" but we had to do because there was no other way around it given the business constraints we had to work with. (I can't give specifics, due to it being production code.)

Comment: @SathikKhan if you really feel that hardcoding is _always_ bad, just start downvoting all the answers you see that exhibit it.  Voting, as long as it's not targeting a user (serial voting), is completely up to you.  Downvote everything if you want to.  You'll just run out of reputation pretty quickly if you downvote every answer with some measure of "hard-coding"

Comment: @ryanyuyu, from my view no solution is bad and no solution deserves down voting. If you like upvote them that's it. I want to have a process, where we can go and tell the people, how to improve the answers, if its hardcoded. I'm not here target a user, I am happy to connect with the people rather than targeting someone.

Comment: @SathikKhan If "no solution is bad and no solution deserves down voting," what is the point of all this? SO doesn't exist to police good coding style or best practices. It exists to collect questions and answers. Good questions and good answers, if they contain code, will very often contain hardcoded values for clarity's sake.

Comment: explain why this is wrong in context of a specific **complete** example; from your comments you are conflating someone showing a very narrow problem with writing a rules engine to replace an `if/else` statement, there is more a problem with that idea than what you are complaining about.

Comment: Please stop closing discussion questions as opinion-based if your opinion is "I strongly disagree".

Answer (score 35):

Yes, we should allow such answers.

SO doesn't exist to give full examples of working applications, complete with configuration files, sample data, and the like. Instead, it focuses on questions and answers, with an emphasis on clear, concise, and specific posts addressing one topic at a time. As a result, 99% of the answers on Main that contain code at all are focused on a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (either creating one or improving one from the question). So, for example, it's much clearer and easier to write this answer:

> A modulo operator is expressed like this, using the `%` sign:
>
> ```
>    17 % 3 // == 2
> ```

than this one:

> A modulo operator is expressed like this, using the `%` sign:
>
> ```
>    int operand, base;
>    int mod(a, n) {
>         return a % n;
>    }
>    loadConfiguration(); // loads operand and base
>    // pretend operand == 17 and base == 3
>    print(mod(operand, base)); // outputs 2
> ```

The first is extremely clear and puts the critical information (use the `%` symbol) front-and-center. The second is extremely unclear, buries the essential information in multiple layers of code, and simply adds noise.

Hardcoded values are often bad in production, like when they are "magic numbers" that may need to change someday. But they're usually essential in writing a concise explanation or example of a concept. And even in production, *some* hardcoded values—the file name and path to a configuration file, or database connection constants in a web app, to give a couple of examples—are almost always essential, or at least practically unavoidable.

SO doesn't exist to police good coding style or best practices. It exists to collect questions and answers. Good questions and good answers, if they contain code, will very often contain hardcoded values for clarity's sake.

So, yes, we should allow such answers. We shouldn't reject, downvote, or refuse to accept otherwise valid answers just because they contain hardcoded values.

Comment: I'm not asking to reject but we should not encourage them. There should be someone to correct those answers. Or Just upvote them but don't mark them as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: @SathikKhan I disagree, for the same reasons I wrote above. There's no need to "correct" an already-correct answer just because it contains a hardcoded value. And a hardcoded value is no reason not to mark a good answer as the accepted answer.

Comment: @EdCottrell Its worth noting that many times production code is written for internal use only. In these cases often people will not bother to write extensive config systems because of time constraints (or that they can reasonably assume the people dealing with it are programmers with access to the source).

Comment: @ed Cottrel, I understand this is your view. But my view is not to encourage hardcoding. We also need to consider how an answer implemented back in production or in real time.

Comment: @Magisch True. That's one reason I say hardcoded values are "often" bad in production.

Comment: @SathikKhan No, we don't need to consider exactly how a user will or should implement an answer in production, and we certainly don't need to write super-complicated code just to avoid hardcoding any strings or numbers. If the answer answers the question and points out any other huge problems, it's a good answer. It's the OP's problem to figure out how best to adapt the concepts in the answer to production code.

Comment: +1 for hard-coding being appropriate and even preferable for "proof of concept" code in answers.

Comment: I was working on an answer myself, but I don't think it'd add much to what you've written here. @SathikKhan This isn't about _encouraging_ hard-coding, it's about whether or not it should be fine in answers. If some programmer out there is going to come here and copy/paste the code into their production code-base and not change it to so much as remove a hard-coded value and make it dynamic... I'm not sure there's much we can _do_ for that particular programmer. They need to learn not to just copy/paste code, and nothing we do about answers here will teach them that.

Comment: @Kendra ^ this. Very well put.

Comment: @Kendra We have to reasonably assume that the people using the answers are not idiots. And what follows is that hardcoded values for demo purposes are fine.

Comment: @Kendra, I am happy to see we are moving in a right direction. So, where there is a note / warning stating that, this code contains "hardcoding". This will help or remind them not use hardcoding.

Comment: @SathikKhan Hardcoding stuff isn't even inherently bad. Its bad for most purposes in industry programming, but not inherently. Its all about the scope of your application and what you need and what you don't.

Comment: @Magisch, Please check my comment above. Thanks.

Comment: @SathikKhan You may be missing the point. There is no need for a note or warning like that. If a user is unable to realize that `if (name == "Robert")` contains a hardcoded value, that person is never going to be a good programmer. A note or warning won't help that.

Comment: @SathikKhan A note/warning not to use hard-coding pointed at _who?_ The user viewing the answer? Great! Let me know how many of them actually read it, after you find _a reliable way_ to identify answers that need the warning. (Make sure it scales! SO is a big site!) The answerer? _Why?_ Why would you want to make showing an unrelated concept harder, and make the answer less clear, by disallowing hard-coding? Not to mention that this _also_ suffers from the "find a reliable way to identify it" issue.

Comment: @Kendra, I guess if you are going to debate by keep answering.... Sorry. By the way I requested you to quote an example where and how the hardcoding is unavoidable.

Comment: Thanks guys... I guess, these comments and discussion  will help for others. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: @SathikKhan Where hardcoding is unavoidable? Well, in your example, there are two choices: Refactor it to use a lookup (*completely different from the original answer* - and is not an option), or define `const string ROBERT = "Robert"` which is a terrible idea. What would you suggest? How would you improve your example?

Answer (score 17):

You seem to be locked in the mindset that an answer on SO, which merely tries to explain a *concept*, must abide by all the best practices one would expect to see in production-ready, enterprise-grade code.

It'd be like saying that I can't use an analogy involving talking animals unless I first explain the biology that enables them to talk and the [socio-economic structure](https://www.overthinkingit.com/2011/02/24/my-little-pony-political-economy/) of a society composed of self-conscious animals when I'm just trying to [describe a moral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aesop%27s_Fables).

[image]

Users who post answers should feel free to discard anything, including best practices, in service of explaining the one concept in need of explanation. The only case where they should absolutely include or at least mention best practice is where that practice is directly related to the question.

If the question is about the most efficient way to branch based on a string value in a given environment, then code samples comparing `if (val == "someval")` to `switch (val){ case "someval": break; }` is totally reasonable.

If the question is about how to internationalize an application and an answer suggests storing strings in a hardcoded array, then yes... that would deserve a downvote, because storing hardcoded strings in an array is a very poor way to internationalize your application.