# Why was my meta question deleted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, meta

My previous [Stack Overflow Meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317555/hard-coded-values-inside-the-app) was deleted. Why was this question deleted?  If my question was unclear, why wasn't I given an opportunity to clarify it?

Comment: @SathikKhan The close reason should be a pretty big hint as to what the problem might be.  Did you read that?

Comment: @SathikKhan Well, you should have given a concise sample of what you're asking about.

Comment: Yeap, I agreed. I someone asked for clarification, I can provide but no one waited for my answer.

Comment: @EdCottrell, I am not complain about anybody just want to ask, this how stackoverflow works and should I stay and answer the questions?

Comment: @SathikKhan As the person asking the questions, you need to do your best to make them clear *before posting*. If you post something that is too confusing, it will get voted down, closed, and possibly deleted. It's your job to write a good question; it's not our job to help you turn a very bad question into a good one.

Comment: @EdCottrell, I am not expecting anyone to help me to ask. but If you don't understand ask for clarification. Ask the developers what HardCoding mean.

Comment: @SathikKhan "this how stackoverflow works" is not a question. If you need help understanding the site, please spend a while reading the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) materials. As for "should I stay and answer the questions," that depends on whether you have a clear and correct answer that you can offer. We're happy to have you here, but your posts have to stand on their merits.

Comment: What do you mean by `Ask the developers what HardCoding mean`? Are you asking us what "hardcoding" means? Are you telling me to ask someone else what that means? Your writing is very unclear. It seems that English may not be your primary language. That's fine, but this is an English-only site, so you may have a hard time finding and giving help here if there is a significant language barrier.

Comment: @EdCottrell This question seems to be asking why his previous meta question was deleted.  I suppose it could get cleaned up a bit, but I don't see *this* question meriting closure.

Comment: @EdCottrell, don't jump into the conclusion. Please read my questions and comment on here.

Comment: @Servy Maybe, but then he needs to say that. In addition to the question, he has posted 6 comments, and the question still does not make sense.

Comment: @EdCottrell, did you try to understand the question instead of you keep jumping into the conclusion and start judging the people.

Comment: @EdCottrell Does that edit help?

Comment: @SathikKhan I'm not jumping to conclusions or judging you. I'm telling you that *your post* is extremely unclear. It did not actually ask a question.

Comment: @Servy I don't know. I debated rolling it back because I'm not at all convinced that's what OP is asking. It would help if OP would say one way or the other. **Edit**: I reopened it because, whether or not that's what OP was going for, it at least asks a useful question now.

Comment: @EdCottrell please tell me what you don't understand from this and previous question.

Comment: @SathikKhan I'm the one arguing that this question is clear enough to understand.  I have no idea at all what your previous question is asking.  I wouldn't even know where to start in asking a clarifying question.

Comment: @SathikKhan: the title of this question is still completely opaque. I have no idea what the question is about by reading the title. (For example. The rest wasn't much clearer.)

Comment: @SathikKhan This question made no sense *and was not a question* until other users edited it. I still don't know if those edits help it say what you wanted to say because I don't know what you were trying to say. With respect to [your other question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317555/hard-coded-values-inside-the-app), I have absolutely no idea what you were asking. No one else did, either, which is why it got voted down, closed, and deleted. As I said above, you need to make your questions clear. If we can't tell what you're asking, we can't help you.

Comment: @EdCottrell, You mean to say, most of them in stackoverflow don't know what "hardcoding" mean?

Comment: @SathikKhan I'm saying I have no idea what *you* are asking. I know what "hardcoding" means, and I'm sure 99% of other users do, too. But I have no idea what `How we are accepting the hardcode values (inside the code) as an answer?` means.

Comment: @EdCottrell There is an answer with the hardcoded values in it. So, I just wanted to ask, should we allow that to be an answer. Hope this make sense to you

Comment: @SathikKhan If you can edit [that question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317555/hard-coded-values-inside-the-app) to say that, then it can probably be undeleted and reopened. But you need to say what you mean by "allow that to be an answer," and you should give at least one example.

Comment: @SathikKhan Sometimes an example is best. Do you have a link to the answer that contains the "hardcoded values"?

Comment: @EdCottrell, did I get a chance to edit that? No, the question gets deleted even before my next login.

Comment: Sometimes a machine translator can be a useful tool.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, I understand and I can start doing it. But not given an opportunity to edit my question.  I will share that question link. Thanks.

Comment: @SathikKhan So go edit it now. Yes, it got deleted quickly, because it was unclear and you didn't respond when multiple people asked you clarifying questions. But you can still edit it and get it undeleted.

Comment: It must have been deleted really quick  I had no chance to downvote it or close vote it as unclear:(

Comment: I am now a machine translator.

Comment: @Will, you made job easy... ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Honestly, that question shouldn't have been deleted.  It was closed for being "unclear", which is very much applicable to the post.  I have no idea what it's actually asking.  That said, there's no reason to *delete* it, at least not within half an hour of it being closed.  You should have been given the opportunity to edit the question to try to clarify what you meant; there were even several comments posted trying to help figure out what was being asked, implying that they think that the post is at least *potentially* salvageable.

If the post was deleted after 30 days by the automatic script, after you not having actually edited it to address any of the problems, then I certainly wouldn't have a problem with that or vote to undelete it, but as is, you simply didn't have an opportunity to address the criticisms via an edit, and the question doesn't seem "unsalvageable".

But while I do think that it shouldn't be deleted, it's certainly nowhere near in a state where it should be reopened.

Comment: I thought we couldn't vote to delete until some time expired. Is that just a fleeting memory of mine, or do you know if reputation of delete voters and downvotes on the question play into that timer?

Comment: @BilltheLizard IIRC the restriction is lifted after 20K

Comment: @BilltheLizard [20k'ers can vote to delete questions scoring -3 or below immediately after they're closed.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user)

Comment: And two days after closure for questions with score >= -2: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177675/159251

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Thanks! They snuck those privileges in when I wasn't paying attention.

Comment: Since I'm one of the delete voters, I will say that I first saw the question got closed and OP got useful comments to improve his post. And when I came back I saw now reaction from OP so I saw no value in having the post around. *at least not within half an hour* OP had over 30 minutes, but I still think a bit more time wouldn't have hurt; If I would have saw a reaction from OP I definitely wouldn't have voted.

Comment: @Rizier123, so 30 - 60 mins are the timeframe to respond back otherwise the post will get deleted?

Comment: @SathikKhan There is no rule when a post gets deleted, but for me I can say that if I would have saw just a comment from you like: "Okay, I will try to clarify my question" I wouldn't have voted on it at least for a few hours.

Comment: @Rizier123 Even several hours is *entirely* too soon to vote to delete a salvageable question.  You should only be voting to delete a question that soon if it's not *possible* for it to be salvaged, rather than because the author hasn't gotten to it yet.

Comment: @Servy I will take your advice and do that it the future, even though I don't like bad questions laying around. (I also noticed in the meanwhile, that if a question on meta gets closed e.g. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/317462 the help center links are for questions on SO, so there might be some improvements to make here. Since tips about asking programming questions and close reasons on the main site aren't really useful to an asker on meta)

Comment: Thanks @Servy, you made the discussion more meaningful. Thanks keep it up.

Comment: @Rizier123 That's... well... horrible. Do you expect someone to be surfing every minute of the day? There's many times when I ask a question, and leave - and come within a few hours to see how things have probably played out. IMO, a question should only be eligible for deletion after 24 hours.

Comment: @Zizouz212 No they don't have to be online all the time. But mostly you already get a response in a few minutes, so you see directly if you missed something or got an answer right away.

Comment: @Rizier123 Well, I sometimes post a question, or an answer - then go find a snack to eat, or get going to my classes at school (I'm 16 btw), or even just go to sleep if it's fairly late at night. If I were to find my question closed, well fine. But deleted would probably be a little overkill for such a short period of time.

Comment: For what it's worth, when I post something I'm chained to my computer for at least an hour to monitor it, whether I need an answer right away or not, lest my post be voted beyond recovery.  (Seriously, how many of your downvotes have you reversed after seeing an edit?  I think my count is in the single digits.)  This has discouraged me from asking some questions regarding problems I worked around myself but would like to know the "true" answer for, because it doesn't seem worth the time cost.  But I think this topic is worth its own meta question, if there isn't one already.

Comment: When one asks a question, they have a certain amount of responsibility. You are expected to put forth effort to ask something coherent that can be reasonably answered. That didn't happen here. The question was a mess and, in my opinion, an eyesore. I have to scratch my head in amazement that you're advocating supporting this behavior, coddling users who can't be bothered to put forth any effort. They had an infinite amount of time to compose a reasonable question *before* they asked it. Why is it our job to give them that time *after* they've asked it? This one wasn't borderline in my mind.

Comment: @CodyGray Closing the question right away is fine.  Deleting every question within minutes of it being closed is simply unacceptable.  It's not what deletion is there for.  Deletion is there for questions that are unredeemable, not for questions that weren't perfect when asked.  Deleting the question is merely forcing them to re-ask the question, instead of editing it, as we *want* them to do.  The author was even entirely willing to improve the question in response to the indications of its problems, and *wasn't given the opportunity*.

Comment: @CodyGray, can you tell me why this question is getting down voted? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35533109/how-to-launch-an-eco-system-with-containers

Comment: @sathik You are asking for open-ended recommendations ("share the best solutions"), which makes it off-topic according to Stack Overflow guidelines. Beyond that, the question is extremely broad and lacks specific details. (Why are you asking me this?)

Comment: It's not open ended, the subject matter expert can understand. even i have got the answer there. If its open ended question, leave comment and ask for clarification, else leave it. Same applies to deleting someones question.

Comment: @SathikKhan If a question merits closure the appropriate thing to do is to vote to close it, not to comment and refuse to vote to close it.  If you can fix the problems with the question so that it no longer merits closure then it can be reopened.

Comment: @Servy, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35533109/how-to-launch-an-eco-system-with-containers did you see any reason to down vote that question?

Answer (score 15):

SO is famous for its fast response time on questions.  You got that, several users posted comments to indicate that they had no idea what you were asking.  And the question was put on hold 5 minutes after you asked it.

If you don't respond at all then users will just assume that you've lost interest.  And votes to delete the question get to be pretty likely since nobody knows what else to do with the question.

Q+A requires both the Questioner and the Answers to participate.  Given the fast response, what you never want to do is walk away.  Not until at least 10 minutes have passed.  If it takes you more time to edit then just post a comment to that effect.

Comment: Questions are to be deleted when it's either *impossible* for the question to be salvaged, or when it's very clear that the author has no interest in salvaging it.  Them not editing it in 10 minutes is not an indication that they have no interest whatsoever in improving the question.  A question should only be deleted that quickly if it is unredeemable, otherwise it should be given at least a few days to be edited.  Closing the question ASAP is of course entirely warranted, and preferable.